# Component not getting mounted using Redirect To of React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

Even though, I'm able to go the route, the Login component associated with the /login route is not getting mounted. There is code for a total of 5 components (App, Login, Auth, Layout3, TopBar) which I've added below. For the Auth component, I'm making use of the 'react-token'auth' package. Please let me know if you have any questions, the code might seem a lot. But you can focus on the code for the TopBar component as that's where I'm redirecting to the login route. And of course, in the App component, I've added the route for Login. So the TopBar and App component is where there might be a problem.

Here is the App component where I have defined all the routes for my application.

```
  class App extends Component {
  render() {
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Layout3} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </StylesProvider>
  }
```

Now, here is the Login component. Here, if the user is logged in, he gets redirected to the '/' route which is the Layout3 component. But if the person isn't logged in, he'll get shown the Login page. I've added the logic for that in the return. UseAuth() points to the Auth.js file where I've imported the createAuthProvider from react-token-auth package.

```
export default function Login(props) {
const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

const onSubmitClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("You pressed login")
    let opts = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    console.log(opts)
    fetch('/api/login', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(opts)
    }).then(r => r.json())
        .then(token => {
            if (token.access_token) {
                login(token)
                // setLoggedIn(true)

                console.log(token)
            }
            else {
                console.log("Please type in correct username/password")
            }
        })
}

const handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value)
}

const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value)
}

const [logged] = useAuth();

console.log('logged or not: ', logged);

return (
    <div style={{
        backgroundColor: 'white', height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}>

        {!logged ?
            <>
                <h1>Please Log In</h1>
                <form>
                    <label>
                        <p>Username</p>
                        <input type="text"
                            onChange={handleUsernameChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <p>Password</p>
                        <input type="password"
                            onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            onClick={onSubmitClick}
                        >Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </>
            :
            <>
                <Redirect to='/' push={true} />
            </>
        }
    </div>
)
}
```

Here is the Auth.js file that I was talking about.

```
  import { createAuthProvider } from 'react-token-auth';


export const [useAuth, authFetch, login, logout] =
createAuthProvider({
    accessTokenKey: 'access_token',
    onUpdateToken: (token) => fetch('/api/refresh', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: token.access_token
    })
        .then(r => r.json())
});
```

Here is the Layout3 component where I'm conditionally going to either the Layout3 comp or the Login comp.

```
   class Layout3 extends Component {

state = {
    authMessage: '',
    loginStatus: false
}

componentDidMount() {
    authFetch("/api/protected").then(response => {
        console.log('response inside authenticationFetch: ', response)
        if (response.status === 401) {
            this.setState({ authMessage: response.status })
            return null
        }
        return response.json()
    }).then(response => {
        if (response && response.message) {
            this.setState({ authMessage: response.message })
        }
    })
}

  render() {

    return (
        <>
            {
                this.state.authMessage === 401 ?
                    <>
                        <BrowserRouter>
                            <Redirect to='/login' />
                        </BrowserRouter>
                    </>
                    :
                    <>
                        <BrowserRouter>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path='/'>
                                <TopBar/>
                            </Switch>
                        </BrowserRouter>
                    </>
                  }
               </>...
```

And finally, here is the TopBar where the logout button is present.

```
 class TopBar extends Component {
     state = {
        loggedOut: false
      }

 dashboardLogOut = () => {
    this.setState({ loggedOut: true });
 }

  render() {

    console.log('state inside topbar ', this.state.loggedOut)
    if (this.state.loggedOut === true) {
        logout()
        return (
            <Redirect from="/" to="/login" push={true} />
        )
    }
    return(
       <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <button onClick={this.dashboardLogOut}>
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
      );
   }
   }
```

Comment: Let me know if anyone has any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export like this `export const [useAuth, authFetch, login, logout]`

It must be a defined variable

```
import { createAuthProvider } from "react-token-auth";

export const useAuthProvider = createAuthProvider({
  accessTokenKey: "access_token",
  onUpdateToken: (token) =>
    fetch("/api/refresh", {
      method: "POST",
      body: token.access_token
    }).then((r) => r.json())
});
```

And later you can use it with a destructuring call in `Login.js`

```
const [useAuth, authFetch, login, logout] = useAuthProvider();
const [logged] = useAuth();
```

Also `Layout3` doesn't look good because it breaks single responsibility principle. Condition based redirection must be implemented on a router level

Comment: That's how they have done in the npm package which I followed. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-token-auth

Comment: "Also Layout3 doesn't look good because it breaks single responsibility principle. Condition based redirection must be implemented on a router level" - Can you expand on how I can add condition based redirection? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Something like this https://dev.to/pprathameshmore/protected-routes-in-react-js-216i .What happens here is that you check if you have an access to a certain endpoint on a route level but not on a component level

Comment: @veralex is the following export permissible, or does it too run into problems? `export const {useAuth, authFetch, login, logout} = createAuthProvider`

Comment: @veralex can I ask you to take a look at my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620971/react-token-auth-why-does-useauth-return-false-then-true-without-navigating