# React Token Auth: Why does useAuth() return false, then true, without navigating or refreshing?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-token-auth and I'm noticing something odd. First, here's my code for createAuthProvider:

```
export const {useAuth, authFetch, login, logout} = createAuthProvider({
  accessTokenKey: 'access_token',
  onUpdateToken: (token) => fetch(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_BACKEND}/refresh`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: token.access_token
    }).then(r => r.json())
});
```

And here's my simple App() component:

```
function App() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isSignedIn] = useAuth();

  console.log('App isSignedIn: ', isSignedIn)
}
```

When I access the page, isSignedIn is logged as false and then without refreshing the page, is logged again as true. From console:

```
App isSignedIn:  false [App.js:33]
App isSignedIn:  true [App.js:33]
```

Why is the value of `isSignedIn` changing without navigation? I don't have React StrictMode enabled, so that can't be the answer.

Comment: Because react is reactive. When the state is updated in the auth context, react re-renders all the components that depend on that state.

Comment: By state, in this context, you mean the `isSignedIn` variable? If so, why is it being updated?

Comment: Why is it being updated? It looks like you've programmed react-token-auth to hit your refresh endpoint and sign users in. You'll have to read the react-token-auth docs to figure out why they do what they do.

Comment: There aren't many docs and they don't answer this. I opened in an issue but thought I should also ask here on StackOverflow